# Keeping colors in <video> consistent accross plugins

Tags: colors, html5-video

A video needs to be shown on a website. I used HTML5 and the  tag with WebM, Theora/OGV and H.264/MP4. This video is looking nice on most browser/OS combinations, but the colors are distorted when watching it with Quicktime on Windows.

Is there a canonical way to ensure consistent colors? If there is not, can I order a browser to not use Quicktime on Windows if an alternative is available?

The current approach is taken from [this tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Testvideo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<center>
<H2>Endeavour</H2>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="endeavour.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
  <source src="endeavour.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis">
  <source src="endeavour.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis">
</video>
</center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100% but the order you supply as sources will determine which video to prefer - if you want the *webm* file to be preferred you simply add it first:

```
...
<source src="endeavour.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis">
<source src="endeavour.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
<source src="endeavour.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis">
...
```

You cannot force a browser to use (or not to use) a specific plugin installed by the user.

As to colors this depends on how the video files are compressed and how they are encoded.